# UnboundLocalError when using += on list. Why is `nonlocal` needed here when directly calling __iadd__ works fine?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-nonlocal, augmented-assignment

Consider this code:

```
def main():
    l = []

    def func():
        l += [1]

    func()
    print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It will produce:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tahsmith/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tahsmith/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 11, in main
    func()
  File "/Users/tahsmith/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 9, in func
    l += [1]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignment
```

This itself can be fixed by either using `nonlocal l` at the start of `func` **or** using `__iadd__` directly instead of `+=`.

Question: Why is `nonlocal` needed here?

This is very surprising to me.

Comment: Where would you assign the return value of `__iadd__` when you call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` is the augmented **assignment** operator; it roughly translates to:

```
def func():
    l = l + [1]
```

If you were to replace `l += [1]` with a call to `object.__iadd__()`, you can't ignore the return value of that call if you were to use it *properly*:

```
def func():
    l = l.__iadd__([1])
```

Both of those translations also need a `nonlocal` statement, because both access `l` and assign back to `l`.

You can get away with ignoring the return value of `object.__iadd__` because list objects are mutable; the list is mutated in-place. But then you may as well use the `list.extend()` call in that case:

```
def func():
    l.extend([1])
```

`list.__iadd__()`, under the covers, calls `list.extend()` before returning `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Because, under the covers, `l += [1]` leads to:

```
l = l + [1]
```

which references the name `l` before that's assigned to; that's why you'll get the `UnboundLocalError`.

`l.__iadd__`, on the other hand, is a simple function call; it *doesn't* perform an assignment thereby negating the need for `nonlocal` to assist in where to look for the name `l`.